# How do set the name of the button to the value of the inputted text?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<tr class="editorRow">
   <td class="emailRow">
      <input id="EmailSuccessList_0" 
             name="EmailSuccessList[0]" 
             type="text" value="asdf@lib.com">
   </td>
   <td>
      <button type="button" href="#" 
              class="deleteEmailRow button sexybutton "
              name="asdf@lib.com">delete</button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I have the following Jquery (whcih works) and need some help with the selectors and/or methods to access/change the name of the `button` base on user input. It seems very clunky to me.

```
$('.emailRow input').live('keyup', function (e) {

      var target = this;
      var currentVal = $(this).val();
      $(target).parent().parent().find('button').attr('name', currentVal)
 });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why change the delete button to the email they have typed? How are you posting this value for deletion?

Comment: @hunter - this markup is part of a table/list of email addresses the user may edit(add/update/delete). So there is definitely a use for 1) deleting something that as been added in error or 2) delete an existing item. wrt to the name part of the button, I have a modal confirmation box which upon delete prompts for confirmation. The message of the box is created using the name part of the button that  was clicked.

Comment: From what I can tell there is no reason for you to sync up the button name attribute with what is in the text box... it's a simple jQuery selector to get that. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I have come up with so far after some Jquery API searching..

```
$(target).closest('tr').find('button').attr('name', currentVal)
```

Comment: Given your markup this is probably as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a dynamically built table you can use delegate:

```
$("table").delegate(".editorRow button").click(function(){
```

or just a regular selector if

```
$(".editorRow button").click(function(){
```

but each either way you can find the email easily

```
    var email = $(this).closest("tr").find("input:text").val();
    // show your dialog
});
```

---

**I can't think of a single reason you would need to sync the button name with the textbox value since you already have it and can find it simply.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#deleteEmailRow').attr('name', currentVal);
```

I guess you could technically even replace `currentVal` like this:

```
$('#deleteEmailRow').attr('name', $(this).val());
```

Comment: my mistake, `deleteEmailRow` should not be an Id

Comment: @Ahmad Oh--well with tables and no `id` attributes, the only way I've ever done it is your "clunky" way ;) I try to incorporate id's for everything

Answer (score 0):

Is this HTML generated by some engine? Like asp, asp.net, asp.net mvc or something similar in Java or other platform (I'm .net guy :))? If so, you could have meaningful ids on your buttons generated the same way you generate ids for inputs. After that, you can easily reference the button from the input's keyup handler.

Comment: Yes - the markup is generated from Asp.Net Razor engine, however, my issue does not lie with binding an event to the button - it lies with new row items that are inserted into the parent table. On a page load, the `name` element is populated with the names of existing items, however when new items are added to the table, the name of the button needs to be updated - this is my problem domain.